# How do I wait for background jobs in the background?

Tags: bash, background-process, jobs

I have the following problem:

```
$ some_command &     # Adds a new job as a background process
$ wait && echo Foo   # Blocks until some_command is finished
$ wait && echo Foo & # Is started as a background job and is done immediately
```

What I would like `wait &` to do is to wait in the background until *all other background jobs* are finished.

Any way I can achieve that?

Comment: Add a `trap` for `CHLD`.

Answer (score 5):

At some point, something has to wait for the execution of commands.
However, if you could place your commands inside a couple of functions, you can schedule them to do what you need:

```
some_command(){
    sleep 3
    echo "I am done $SECONDS"
}

other_commands(){
    # A list of all the other commands that need to be executed
    sleep 5
    echo "I have finished my tasks $SECONDS"
}

some_command &                      # First command as background job.
SECONDS=0                           # Count from here the seconds.
bg_pid=$!                           # store the background job pid.
echo "one $!"                       # Print that number.
other_commands &                    # Start other commands immediately.
wait $bg_pid && echo "Foo $SECONDS" # Waits for some_command to finish.
wait                                # Wait for all other background jobs.
echo "end of it all $SECONDS"       # all background jobs have ended.
```

If the sleep times are as shown in the code, 3 and 5, then some_command will end before the rest of the jobs, and this will be printed on execution:

```
one 760
I am done 3
Foo 3
I have finished my tasks 5
end of it all 5
```

If the sleep times are (for example) 8 and 5, this will be printed:

```
one 766
I have finished my tasks 5
I am done 8
Foo 8
end of it all 8
```

Note the order. Also the fact that each part has ended as soon as it was possible for itself (the value of `$SECONDS` printed).